# Is FIreFTP no longer an addon for Waterfox?

Tags: waterfox, fireftp

(56.2.8(64 bit)I started using FireFTP when Firefox supported it and LOVE it, but, when they stopped supporting it and the developer said Waterfox would support it, I began using Waterfox just because I love FireFTP. I had no issue getting it to work. BUT, now I have a new laptop, downloaded Waterfox and there is no extension for FireFTP and it's the same exact version I was using on my old labtop (56.2.8(64 bit). I went to the developer's site, and downloaded the zip file, but, need help figuring out how to install it (I honestly do not know how to do it) If someone can help me, please do a step by step explanation on how to install it to my browser since I'm not a developer and may get confused. I really want to use FireFTP in Waterfox.

PS, Has anyone else experienced this or are others still seeing it as an addon? My Waterfox browser says there is no add on for FireFTP (56.2.8(64 bit). HELP! I love my FireFTP and would like to have it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of FireFTP/FireSSH. You should be able to just click on 'fireftp_all.xpi' and it will popup asking for your permission to install the addon. See [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xk9rtwx1fib1j0m/Screenshot%202019-05-05%2021.31.47.png?dl=0) as an example. If it doesn't popup, you'll probably see the jigsaw icon in the address bar and you can try clicking on that.

Alternatively, go to Tools->Add-ons->Gear Icon->Install Add-ons From File...
([screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h10n7eznbhhrq7n/Screenshot%202019-05-05%2021.34.40.png?dl=0) of that process)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect instruction and easy, but, Waterfox tells me "The add-on downloaded from this site could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt." I tried it numerous times to be sure, but the same window keeps popping up.

Comment: I KNEW this would happen!! I tried at least 10 times clicking the file and got the error message. I sent my comment and thought I'd go ahead and try again. It worked JUST FINE. Go figure. How embarrassing on my part, but how WONDERFUL it installed perfectly. I love your software and appreciate so much your help!!! THANK YOU!! I pray that Waterfox doesn't change it's support of your software for any reason. Keep your site updated because I'll always check it should we have to change browsers again. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!!!!

Comment: Dear mimecuvalo. I hope you're still getting questions from this forum. It's a year later and I find myself in the same situation where I cannot get FIreFTP to install to Waterfox. I have a different computer now and did exactly what you instructed me to do last year (clicking the fireftp_all.xpi to install the file and show up under  Tools/Web Developer ) but while it downloads, when it goes to install it continues to say the file is corrupt. This time is won't install at all after many, many, many tries. Suggestion? I love your program.